# Cordova Crosswalk file selection no app can perform this action error

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk-project

I am creating an android app using Cordova with the Crosswalk webview and the dtworkshop-inappcrossbrowser plugin. The app is effectively wrapping a website.

On the website there is a form that allows you to upload a photo. The problem is that when I select the browse button I get the message "Choose an action" followed by "No apps can perform this action".

I am not totally sure how the upload button functions, but I know that it is not an input element because I experimented with an input and I know it works.

I read that it could be a permissions so I have added the following, but still no luck:

READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, INTERNET, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE, ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, CAMERA, MANAGE_DOCUMENTS.

I have tested in the android chrome browser and everything works, so I know its related to the app.

I have created the same app for iOS and everything works. I know there are issues with the android webview hence the reason I am using the crosswalk plugin,  thought these issues were going to be solved.

Any help advice about how I can get this working is much appreciated.

Comment: Ever reach a conclusion @ee0jmt

Comment: No sorry @simbolo I ended up not using the crosswalk plugin and instead using the chrome tabs plugin to view that page.

Answer (score 3):

Hey I have found that editing the accept="" attribute to accept="image/*" or accept="video/*" fixed the problem. Also attribute such as .ext or more than one attribute i.e accept="image/*, video/*" though syntax wise are correct will throw the same error. Hope this helps

Comment: In my case `accept="image/png"` worked. But thanks for right direction anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was due to the fact I was not including `cordova.js` as script in my `index.html` file.

So I simply added the following line to `index.html` and it was working fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
```